# Hashtag detection from a chunk of text, in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, hashtag

I am looking to create a php script that detects twitter style hashtags from a chunk  of text. So it would search for #then_a_word.

Comment: Simple regex is your friend...

Comment: If you're using the Twitter API, this can help: http://dev.twitter.com/pages/tweet_entities

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using a regex and [**`preg_match_all()`**](http://fr.php.net/preg_match_all), you could have something like this :

```
$str = <<<STR
this is a string
with a #tag and
another #hello one
STR;

$matches = array();
if (preg_match_all('/#([^\s]+)/', $str, $matches)) {
  var_dump($matches[1]);
}
```

Which gives the following output :

```
array
  0 => string 'tag' (length=3)
  1 => string 'hello' (length=5)
```

And, if you need to do a bit more manipulations on those, you should take a look at the [**PCRE Functions**](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/ref.pcre.php) section of the manual : there are some others that might help you.

Comment: As far as I can tell *(this question/asnwer is a bit old, and I don't remember it that well)*, that's precisely what was asked, here; is it not ?

Comment: Yes, I created another question because I made a mistake while writing this one.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$str = "I LIKE BURGERS"; // for example
$pattern = "\burgers\i";
echo "$pattern, "BURGERS", $str";

?>
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please, when answering a question, detail your answer and clarify what it does and why do you think it will solve the question. Don't post just code.